# Use liferay-ui:asset-categories-selector tag to offer one vocabulary only

Tags: liferay, taglib, categorization, vocabulary, liferay-6.2

I'm developing a Liferay portlet supposed to offer a way of categorizing its content. I created multiple vocabularies (e.g. frogs, apes, birds).

In the view of THIS portlet I want to offer the categories of the "frogs"-vocabulary only. I know I could write some code to read the categories contained in the vocabulary to offer them in a combo-box.

But, isn't there a way of convincing the built-in liferay-ui:asset-categories-selector-tag to show *one vocabulary only*? Or may be there's some other tag? (I'm stuck here.)

Here's my current code that lists all vocabularies:

```
<liferay-ui:asset-categories-selector
    className=" <%= JournalArticle.class.getName() %>"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this [taglib's documentation](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/taglibs/liferay-ui/asset-categories-selector.html) is quite tumbleweed. You might need to look into the implementation for the actual content of the attribute, but `curCategoryIds` might be a good choice to start trying out if this is foreseen.

Alternatively it might be worth creating another tag (based on this one, in a new taglib) - if you do this, you might want to file an [issue or feature request](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS) and contribute it back into the liferay-ui taglib.

Comment: Hi Olaf. I will give that attribute a try and come back with the results.

Comment: The parameter curCategoryIds defines a pre-selection. So this sadly is not a solution. I might create an own tag and contribute it as early as I got the time.

Comment: Could you try attribute hiddenInput?  The value for it should be the list of category Ids you don't want to show.